# example of a topological space such that there exists a sequence that escapes to infinity but has convergent subsequence

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Find an example of a topological space such that there exists a sequence that escapes to infinity but has a convergent subsequence

This actually is from exercise 2.15 of introduction to smooth manifolds by John Lee. In that book we knew that if $X$ is a topological manifold, then a sequence escapes to infinity(any compact subspace can only contain finitely many points in the sequence )is equivalent to having no convergent subsequence. However, I think that this might not be true in a general topological space. For example, if $X$ is not metrizable. But I have difficulty finding one.

Comment: I think the question is actually asking for the opposite, based on the commentary in the question description. There's an if and only if statement provided, and a question as to whether/when it may break down in more general settings.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes. You are right, I meant to ask for an example that excapes to infinity but has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @Cameron: I don’t think that the sequence there does escape to infinity: the compact subset $\omega\cup\{p\}$ contains infinitely many points of it.

Comment: @CameronBuie That it interesting but it seems pretty advanced in presentation. Maybe it would be good for the OP to get a simpler example if possible, depending on their background level?

Comment: I checked the question, but I am afraid that I don't understand the construction as I am not quite familier with Stone-Cech compactification nor ultrafilters.

Comment: @Alex: Do you consider the sequence $\langle 0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\ldots\rangle$ to escape to infinity? Infinitely many **terms** are in the compact set $\{0\}$, though only finitely many **points** of the sequence are.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that's a good clarification question

Comment: @Brian: Hmmm...drat. Right you are (it's just not closed). It's still a good answer, though. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the relevant definition in Lee’s *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* at Google Books: a sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in the space $X$ *escapes to infinity* if for each compact $K\subseteq X$, $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in K\}$ is finite. In other words, $\sigma$ escapes to infinity if no compact set in $X$ contains infinitely many **terms** of the sequence.

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space, and suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to $x\in X$. Let $K=\{x\}\cup\{x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\}$; $K$ is a compact set containing infinitely many terms of $\sigma$, so $\sigma$ does not escape to infinity. Thus, a sequence that escapes to infinity has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: So you gave an example of a sequence at does not escape to infinity but has a convergent subsequence. And this seems to contradict with the exercise in that book, so I think it might mean to be not having finitely many points in a compact set K?

Comment: @Alex: No, I showed that if the ambient space is $T_1$, a sequence that escapes to infinity never has a convergent subsequence. This does not contradict the exercise; on the contrary, it shows that at least one implication holds in all $T_1$ spaces. And I was using Lee’s own definition, which counts terms, not points.

Comment: @ Brian M.Scott: Then we also know if a sequence has no convergent subsequence, then it must escape to infinity because if a compact set $K$ contains infinitely many points, (or finitely many points but infinitely many terms), then there must be a limit in $K$.  You have proved that in $T_1$ spaces, the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: But is there any space where the two conditions are not equivalent, i.e. a sequence has a convergent subsequence but escapes to infinity?

Comment: @Alex: In general a sequence in a compact set need not have a convergent subsequence: compact spaces are not necessarily sequentially compact. Compactness and sequential compactness **are** equivalent in metric spaces, so there you do get the converse. The space $\beta\omega$ (or $\beta\Bbb N$), the Čech-Stone compactification of the natural numbers, is a compact space in which the only convergent sequences are the trivial ones, i.e., those that are eventually constant. Thus, the sequence $\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence but does not escape to infinity.

Comment: @Alex: For the other question, I just proved that if a sequnce has a convergent subsequence, it does **not** escape to infinity (at least in $T_1$ spaces).

Comment: @ Brian M.Scott: But compactness implies limit point compact, and doesn't limit point compact imply sequentially compact?

Comment: @Alex: No, it doesn’t. In metric spaces it does, and you’re probably used to that setting.

Comment: Okay, I see, thank you very much.

Comment: @Alex: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @ Brian M.Scott: So is every topological manifold metrizable?

Comment: @Alex: It depends on your definition of *manifold*; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold) for a brief discussion.

Comment: M.Scott: What if the definition includes Hausdorff, locally Euclidean and 2nd countable? Then is it metrizable?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it is. Locally Euclidean and Hausdorff imply that it’s $T_3$, and second countable $T_3$ spaces are metrizable by the Uryson metrization theorem.